# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una práctica muy sencilla para un login, y no encuentro el error que causa que el event listener me dé null. Probé de diferentes maneras, pero me sigue dando error.
Les dejo aquí mi código SCRIPT:

```
    <script>
const form = document.getElementById("formulario");

const enviarFormulario = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
const {name, userid, password} = event.target;
console.log(name.value, userid.value, password.value);
}

form.addEventListener("submit", enviarFormulario);
</script>
```

y el HTML:

```
<main>
<section style="margin: 10%;">
<form id="formulario">
<div class="form-group" action="">
    <input name="userid" type="email" placeholder="Email" required style="width: 30%; height: 5%;">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input name="password" type="text" placeholder="Password" required style="width: 30%; height: 5%;">
</div>

<button type="submit" style="width: 30%; height: 5%;"> Acceder </button>
</form> 
</section>
</main>
```

¿Encuentran el error?

Comment: El `<script>` debe ir antes de cerrar el `<body>`...

Comment: Tu id aún no existe en el DOM cuando tratás de asignarle el _escuchador_ del evento. Te recomiendo que leas acerca del evento [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).

Comment: No creo que este sea el error... no veo que usas a `name` en el DOM, por lo tanto, `name` y `name.value` estarían demás, dan undefined...

Comment: El código funciona perfecto, el script debería funcionar aunque lo pongas incluso fuera del body o incluso fuera de <html>, aunque lo recomendable es agregarlo o en otro archivo o antes de cerrar el body.
Por otro lado no hay un input para name por lo que name da undefined en el console.log.
Quizás puedas subir el código completo para probar, o puede que tengas otro eventListener que esté intentando escuchar sobre algo que esté mal definido, es lo que te está marcando el error... No podés escuchar el evento de algo undefined.

Comment: Trasladé el script a una sheet diferente y ahora tengo un error diferente: Uncaught ReferenceError: documen is not defined

Comment: Fijate que estés poniendo "document" y no "documen" como pasaste en el mensaje.
document es un objeto global, a no ser que lo escribas mal o estés ejecutándolo fuera del navegador, siempre estará presente.

Comment: Tenías razón Luis, de tanto cambiar cosas había escrito mal "document". Lo corregí y ahora sigo en el error inicial.

Comment: El codigo completo es el de la consulta. Borre la parte del 'name', ya que me había faltado ese input efectivamente. No hay otros eventListener, por lo que debe ser otra la razón del error :(

Answer (score 1):

Compañeros, muchas gracias por todos sus mensajes. Finalmente logré resolver el problema como les comparto aquí abajo. Les dejo el SCRIPT:

```
const formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");

const enviarFormulario = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

const { userid, password } = event.target;
console.log(userid.value, password.value);

}

formulario.addEventListener("submit", enviarFormulario);
```

Y el HTML:

```
    <html>
<body>
<section style="margin: 10%;">
<form id="formulario">
<div>
    <input name="userid" id="userid" type="email" placeholder="Email" required style="width: 30%; height: 5%;">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input name="password" id="password" type="text" placeholder="Password" required style="width: 30%; height: 5%;">
</div>

<button id="button" type="submit" style="width: 30%; height: 5%;"> Acceder </button>
</form> 
</section>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Saludos!